# How do I use the activex dll in PHP?

Tags: php, capicom

I want to load an ActiveX DLL in my PHP page and load its functions.

For example: CAPICOM.DLL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend is possible.
Code:

```
<?php   
try{
$signedData = $_POST['datatosign'];

$verification = new \COM("CAPICOM.SignedData");
$verification->Verify($signedData,false,0);
$signIsOk = true;
foreach ($verification->Certificates as $certificate)
{               
}

}catch(\Exception $ex){
$signIsOk = false;
echo $ex->getMessage();     
}

?>
```

this code work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. CAPICOM has been discontinued — it is not available for Windows 7 or later.

For a list of alternatives to CAPICOM, please see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778518.aspx

Comment: Hi. You known any way??